# using assertz() and retract() in breadth-first search

Tags: prolog, breadth-first-search

I am trying to write breadth-first search in SWI Prolog using assertz() and retract(). I am having some issues though and I was hoping for some guidance. My guess is I'm doing something stupid.

```
:- dynamic paths/1.

bfs_solve(Solution) :-
  initial_state(Start),
  assertz(paths([[Start]])),
  breadthfirst(Solution).

breadthfirst([Node | Path]) :-
  retract(paths([[Node | Path] | _])),
  goal(Node).

breadthfirst(Solution) :-
  retract(paths([Path | RestPaths])),
  extend(Path, NewPaths),
  conc(RestPaths, NewPaths, Paths1),
  assertz(paths(Paths1)),
  breadthfirst(Solution).

extend([Node | Path], NewPaths) :-
  bagof([NewNode, Node | Path],
  (s(Node, NewNode), \+ member(NewNode, [Node | Path])),
  NewPaths),
  !.

extend(Path, []).

initial_state([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).
goal([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]).

% Function 's' is not detailed here as it is irrelevant to this problem

member(X, [X | Tail]).
member(X, [Head | Tail]) :-
  member(X, Tail).

conc([], L, L).
conc([X | L1], L2, [X | L3]) :-
  conc(L1, L2, L3).
```

The problem is that as soon as the goal check happens in `breadthfirst/1`, it retracts the initial state from the database, so by the time it gets to the second definition of `breadthfirst/1` (where the `extend/2` function is called), there is nothing left to retract, causing execution to stop.

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Usual reminder: You can step through your program, to see exactly what is happening and where it is going wrong, using e.g. `trace.` - https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debugger

Comment: Looks similar to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xH-AZonBywI - don't need `assertz`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips @brebs! However I'm aware of the standard way of doing breadth-first search in Prolog using dynamic lists. The idea is to not use dynamic lists, but rather a static queue, hence the use of assertz and retract.

Comment: Do not use the database for a queue. It is way easier to use a list. See for example [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31918227/difference-lists-in-prolog-and-mutable-variables)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to figure out your mistakes if you wrapped your calls to assert* and retract* inside a couple of predicates that implement a queue. What do you need for a queue?

- Initialize an empty queue
- push to the back
- pop from the front

(do you also need to be able to push to the front, or look at the top without popping?)

I am assuming that you want to keep this stateful and global? (why use the database otherwise?) In this case you can choose to call your queue `queue/1` and then:

```
:- dynamic queue/1.

empty_queue :-
    retractall(queue(_)).

push_back(Back) :-
    assertz(queue(Back)).

pop_front(Front) :-
    once(queue(F0)), % first fact matched to a free variable
    once(retract(queue(F0))), % retract exactly once the matched fact
    Front = F0.
```

A simple test, I push [a, b, c], pop out twice, so it should be 'a', then 'b', and print the rest of the queue, should be [c]:

```
?- empty_queue,
   push_back(a),
   push_back(b),
   push_back(c),
   pop_front(X0),
   pop_front(X1),
   forall(queue(A), format("~w~n", [A])).
c
X0 = a,
X1 = b.
```

(the whole queue is on the first line of the output)

To show that we only pop the top:

```
?- empty_queue,
   push_back(a),
   push_back(b),
   push_back(a),
   pop_front(X),
   forall(queue(A), format("~w~n", [A])).
b
a
X = a.
```

So it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know that using a dynamic predicate is not the best approach to solving the problem. Anyway, a possible solution using dynamic predicate is as follows:

```
:- dynamic paths/1.

solve(Solution) :-
    initial(State),
    assertz(paths([[State]])),
    bfs(Solution).

bfs(Solution) :-
    retract(paths([[Node|Path]|Paths])),
    writeln(queue: [[Node|Path]|Paths]),
    (   goal(Node)                          % if
    ->  reverse([Node|Path], Solution)      % then
    ;   extend([Node|Path], NewPaths),      % else
        append(Paths, NewPaths, Paths1),
        assertz(paths(Paths1)),
        bfs(Solution) ).

extend([Node|Path], NewPaths) :-
    findall([NewNode,Node|Path],
            (s(Node, NewNode), \+ member(NewNode, [Node|Path])),
            NewPaths).

initial(1).
goal(5).
s(1, 2).
s(1, 3).
s(2, 1).
s(2, 4).
s(3, 4).
s(4, 5).
```

Example:

```
?- solve(S).
queue:[[1]]
queue:[[2,1],[3,1]]
queue:[[3,1],[4,2,1]]
queue:[[4,2,1],[4,3,1]]
queue:[[4,3,1],[5,4,2,1]]
queue:[[5,4,2,1],[5,4,3,1]]
S = [1, 2, 4, 5].
```