# Understanding Prolog's empty lists

Tags: list, prolog, empty-list

I am reading Bratko's *Prolog: Programming for Artificial Intelligence*. The easiest way for me to understand lists is visualising them as binary trees, which goes well. However, I am confused about the empty list `[]`. It seems to me that it has two meanings.

1. When part of a list or enumeration, it is seen as an actual (empty) list element (because somewhere in the tree it is part of some Head), e.g. `[a, []]`
2. When it is the only item inside a Tail, it isn’t an element it literally is *nothing*, e.g. `[a|[]]`

My issue is that I do not see the logic behind 2. Why is it required for lists to have this possible ‘nothingness’ as a final tail? Simply because the trees have to be binary? Or is there another reason? (In other words, why is `[]` counted as an element in 1. but it isn't when it is in a Tail in 2?) Also, are there cases where the final (rightmost, deepest) final node of a tree is not ‘nothing’?

Comment: Lists are actually simpler than trees. They're more like strings; so much so that in some languages strings are defined as lists of characters. The empty list is for lists, what the empty string is for strings.

Comment: `[a, [1,2]]` is a valid list of two elements where the first element is `a` and the second element is a list `[1,2]`. Same idea as `[a, []]`: a list of two elements, first being `a`, second being the empty list  `[]`. You can also have `[a | [1,2]]` which is a list with head `a` and tail `[1, 2]`, the same as `[a, 1, 2]`. So both 1 & 2 in your question treat `[]` consistently as a list. I'm not sure I understand what you mean when you say, *... **required** for lists to have this possible ‘nothingness’ as a final tail*. It is not really *required*, but merely a property. Just like `a + 0 = a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In other words, why is [] counted as an element in 1. but it isn't when it is in a Tail in 2?

Those are two different things. Lists in Prolog are (degenerate) binary trees, but also very much like a singly linked list in a language that has pointers, say C.

In C, you would have a `struct` with two members: the value, and a pointer to the next list element. Importantly, when the pointer to next points to a sentinel, this is the end of the list.

In Prolog, you have a functor with arity 2: `./2` that holds the value in the first argument, and *the rest of the list* in the second:

```
.(a, Rest)
```

The sentinel for a list in Prolog is the special `[]`. This is *not a list*, it is the empty list! Traditionally, it is an *atom*, or a functor with arity 0, if you wish.

In your question:

- `[a, []]` is actually `.(a, .([], []))`
- `[a|[]]` is actually `.(a, [])`

which is why:

```
?- length([a,[]], N).
N = 2.
```

This is now a list with two elements, the first element is `a`, the second element is the empty list `[]`.

```
?- [a|[]] = [a].
true.
```

This is a list with a single element, `a`. The `[]` at the tail just closes the list.

Question: what kind of list is `.([], [])`?

> Also, are there cases where the final (rightmost, deepest) final node of a tree is not ‘nothing’?

Yes, you can leave a free variable there; then, you have a "hole" at the end of the list that you can fill later. Like this:

```
?- A = [a, a|Tail], % partial list with two 'a's and the Tail
   B = [b,b], % proper list
   Tail = B. % the tail of A is now B
A = [a, a, b, b], % we appended A and B without traversing A
Tail = B, B = [b, b].
```

You can also make circular lists, for example, a list with infinitely many `x` in it would be:

```
?- Xs = [x|Xs].
Xs = [x|Xs].
```

Is this useful? I don't know for sure. You could for example get a list that repeats `a, b, c` with a length of 7 like this:

```
?- ABCs = [a,b,c|ABCs], % a list that repeats "a, b, c" forever
   length(L, 7), % a proper list of length 7
   append(L, _, ABCs). % L is the first 7 elements of ABCs
ABCs = [a, b, c|ABCs],
L = [a, b, c, a, b, c, a].
```

In R at least many functions "recycle" shorter vectors, so this might be a valid use case.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26967655/1812457) for a discussion on difference lists, which is what `A` and `Rest` from the last example are usually called.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31925828/1812457) for implementation of a queue using difference lists.

Comment: I'm on mobile now so I'll just give a quick reply. First, thank you for your extensive reply! Seeing the tail as a 'pointer' to the next item makes sense. I don't quite get the part in the final non-empty Tail, though. Can't you write your A as `[a,a|[b|[b|[]]]]`? Meaning, it eventually will need that empty list to finish?

Comment: I added a bit more detail. Make sure to read also the two other answers I linked, they talk quite a bit about the uses of "partial lists". As for `[a,a|[b|[b|[]]]]`, yes, but the point is that if you keep the (free) `Rest` in your hand, you can use it at a later time point to do something with it (again, see the linked answers, too).

Comment: @BramVanroy you can try the `X = [1|[2|3]].` query. It returns with `X = [1, 2|3].`. And `X = [1|[2|[]]].` returns with `X = [1, 2].`. Which makes sense, because `[1, 2|[]] = [1, 2].` returns **true**.

Comment: @WillNess You should have mentioned that `[1, 2|3]` is not a valid list!

Comment: "valid" as interpreted by `is_list/1`, yes.

Comment: @WillNess I guess the right term is "well-formed" or "proper"? I am not sure, really. Even the [SWI-Prolog documentation of `is_list/1`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=is_list/1) avoids using any English for this and instead shows a possible native Prolog definition for `is_list/1`, plus a "cyclic list" disclaimer.

Comment: Your link gives a perfectly clear recursive English definition: "Term is bound to the empty list ([]) or a term with functor ''[|]'' and arity 2 and the second argument is a list." There is no way `[1,2|3]` satisfies this. `[1,2|3]` is also invalid as interpreted by `length/2` and as a first argument of `append/3`, BTW.

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie Yep, it _defines_ what `is_list/1` does, but it doesn't _name_ it in any other way than calling it, well, a list. I was answering to Will Ness, who commented that `[1, 2|3]` is not a "valid" list _as interpreted by_ `is_list/1` (so, maybe valid in some other way?)

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie I could define the following predicate: `foo(3, 3).
foo([X|Xs], [Y|Ys]) :- Y is 2*X, foo(Xs, Ys).` With this, I get: `?- foo([1,2|3], R). R = [2,4|3].` So I guess I can make it work ;-)

Comment: @Boris I just wanted a notion of "valid list" to have a concrete meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Your confusion comes from the fact that lists are *printed* (and read) according to a special human-friendly format. Thus:

```
[a, b, c, d]
```

... is syntactic sugar for `.(a, .(b, .(c, .(d, []))))`.

The `.` predicate represents two values: the item stored in a list and a sublist. When `[]` is present in the `data` argument, it is printed as data.
In other words, this:

```
[[], []]
```

... is syntactic sugar for `.([], .([], []))`.
The last `[]` is not printed because in that context it does not need to. It is only used to mark the end of current list. Other `[]` are lists stored in the main list.

> I understand that but I don't quite get why there is such a need for that final empty list.

The final empty list is a convention. It could be written `empty` or `nil` (like Lisp), but in Prolog this is denoted by the `[]` atom.
Note that in prolog, you can leave the sublist part uninstantiated, like in:

```
[a | T]
```

which is the same as:

```
.(a, T)
```

Those are known as [difference lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26966055/124319).

Comment: I understand that but I don't quite get why there is such a need for that final empty list. Perhaps the idea of 'the pointer to nothing' as Boris suggests is the best way to look at it.

Comment: @BramVanroy Not a pointer to nothing, to a sentinel. Or at least the value of this "nothing" need to be well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of 1. and 2. is correct -- where by "nothing" you mean, element-wise. Yes, an empty list has nothing (i.e. no elements) inside it.

The logic behind having a special sentinel value `SENTINEL = []` to mark the end of a cons-cells chain, as in `[1,2,3]` = `[1,2|[3]]` = `[1,2,3|SENTINEL]` = `.(1,.(2,.(3,SENTINEL)))`, as opposed to some ad-hoc encoding, like `.(1,.(2,3))` = `[1,2|3]`, is *types consistency*. We want the first field of a cons cell (or, in Prolog, the first argument of a `.` functored term) to *always* be treated as "a list's element", and the second -- as "a list". That's why `[]` in `[1, []]` counts as a list's element (as it appears as a 1st argument of a `.`-functored compound term), while the `[]` in `[1 | []]` does not (as it appears as a *2nd* argument of such term).

Yes, the trees have to be binary -- i.e. the functor `.` as used to encode lists *is* binary -- and so what should we put there in the final node's *tail* field, that would signal to us that it *is* in fact the final node of the chain? It must be *something*, consistent and easily testable. And it must also represent the empty list, `[]`. So it's only logical to use the representation of an empty list to represent the empty tail of a list.

And yes, having a non-`[]` final "tail" is perfectly valid, like in `[1,2|3]`, which is a perfectly valid Prolog *term* -- it just isn't a representation of a list `{1 2 3}`, as understood by the rest of Prolog's built-ins.

Comment: I understand it now *I think*. I never had any fundamentals of programming, so I know how to *use* a lot of programming languages but in many cases I want to ge more in-depth and find out *why* a language works this or that way. Thank you for your reply (+1), however I am going to accept Boris' answer because of its examples and the reference to pointers in C, which makes the concept easier to imagine.

Comment: the "cons cell" that I mention is also a reference to pointers ... [*in Lisp*](http://www-formal.stanford.edu/jmc/recursive.html). :)

Comment: Indeed, I found that out when I looked up the term.